# Beginning GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

My question is when I don't mess around with ipadx and ipady. My buttons stick together, but when I do mess around with the ipadx and ipady I find the third button moves one cell away. Why and how can I fix this mess?
CODE:

```
public class Testagain extends JFrame {

    private JPanel pan1;
    private JPanel pan2;
    private JPanel pan3;


    private JButton btn1;
    private JButton btn2;
    private JButton btn3;


    public Testagain()
    {
        super("Panel TEST GRID");
        super.setSize(500, 500);

        btn1 = new JButton(" 1");
        pan1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints con1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        con1.gridx = 0;
        con1.gridy = 0;
        con1.ipadx = 80;
        con1.ipady = 60;
        pan1.add(btn1,con1);

        btn2 = new JButton("2");
        pan2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints con2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        con2.ipady = 60;
        con2.ipadx = 0;
        con2.gridx = 1;
        con2.gridy = 0;
        pan1.add(btn2,con2);



        btn3 = new JButton("3");
        pan3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints con3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        con3.ipady = 60;
        con3.ipadx = 0;
        con3.gridx = 2;
        con3.gridy = 0;


        pan3.add(btn3,con3);


        Container tain = super.getContentPane();
        tain.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        tain.add(pan1,con1);
        tain.add(pan2,con2);
        tain.add(pan3,con3);






        super.setVisible(true);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Testagain();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're adding `btn1` and `btn2` to `pan1`, so `pan2` is been given it's own cell

Comment: Should I give each button a Jpanel? Yes i see the mistake.

Comment: Why?  You're also using the same constraints for each panel as you did for the buttons, which is why you've ended up with the gap. I don't see the benefit of putting a single button on a panel this way, but that's me

Answer (score 1):

You're adding `btn1` and `btn2` to the `pan1`, so `pan2` is been given it's own cell...

```
btn1 = new JButton(" 1");
pan1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//...
pan1.add(btn1,con1);

btn2 = new JButton("2");
pan2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//...
pan1.add(btn2,con2);
```

So, I played around with your code a little, removed some of the complexity which was messing with my head and was able to generate the expected output

[image: Expected Output]

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Testagain extends JFrame {

    private JPanel pan1;
    private JPanel pan2;
    private JPanel pan3;

    private JButton btn1;
    private JButton btn2;
    private JButton btn3;

    public Testagain() {
        super("Panel TEST GRID");
        super.setSize(500, 500);

        GridBagConstraints con1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        btn1 = new JButton(" 1");
        btn2 = new JButton("2");
        btn3 = new JButton("3");

        Container tain = super.getContentPane();
        tain.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        con1.gridx = 0;
        con1.gridy = 0;
        con1.ipadx = 80;
        con1.ipady = 60;
        tain.add(btn1, con1);
        con1.ipadx = 0;
        con1.gridx = 1;
        con1.gridx = 60;
        tain.add(btn2, con1);
        con1.gridx = 2;
        tain.add(btn3, con1);

        super.setVisible(true);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testagain();
    }
}
```

I don't know why you're using intermediate panels to simpy add a single button, but since the button and the panel are using the same constraints, it seems some what "weird" to me, but this might be a snapshot of something larger, I don't know

Comment: Actually a program exercise, requires me to add components to panels and then add panels to the Container. I am learning java on my own. How does it affect the overall appearance.

Comment: To my mind, there's no need to set the layout of the panels to use a `GridBagLayout`, you can get the same effect using a `BorderLayout`, then using the `GridBagLayoutConstraints` for the individual panels, otherwise your simply compounding the constraints, which may not give you the effect you desire